# json schema validator how to get extra field

Tags: java, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I define a json shema like this

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string",
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string",
    },
    "age": {
      "type": "integer"
    }
  }
}
```

and here is my json

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "age": 21,
  "abcd": "how to get this field",
  "efg": "and this field"
}
```

I want to get the extra field which is not defined in json schema, just like "abcd" and "efg".
Output like this: ["abcd","efg"]

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I revised it again, could you please look again?

Comment: Are you asking how to ignore the JSON Schema and retrieve that "extra" field anyway? Answer will depend on which JSON library you're using, so we cannot answer that. --- Or are you asking how to define a JSON Schema that allows "extra" fields?

Comment: I use [json schema](https://github.com/networknt/json-schema-validator), and the json is passed. In addtion,  the field "abcd" and "efg" are not defined in json schema, so is there any method or JSON library to get the fileds. output is like ["abcd","efg"]

Comment: I think I understand. You're asking how to get properties which are not defined in properties in your schema, right? You'll have to write your own solution to that. For a single level object, this is quite easy, but for many nested levels, this is a very difficult problem.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this @ZepheryWen ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a random property (like abcd) instead of generic( firstName, lastname, age), it would be better if you have a map object in your JSON schema, where you can fill in any key, value pairs ( like abcd - "how to get this field").

```
 {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "age": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "attributes": {"$ref": "#/definitions/StringMap"}
  },
  "required": [
    "firstName",
    "lastName",
    "age"
  ],
  "definitions": {
    "StringMap": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": {"type": "string"}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Emmmm,,,,thanks. But the json data is user-sending, i have no idea what they send. Example, they send a data that contains "abcd" and "efg" which is not defined in json schema, i need to get the "abcd" and "efg" field, so i can tell them to fix it.

Comment: Yes in that case you have to ask for change in JSON fields and get those values which are in line with your JSON schema. Please accept my answer if it answers your query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how the JSON schema is changed to reject the input if extra properties are added by the user. In that case, you can set additionalProperties to false.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string",
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string",
    },
    "age": {
      "type": "integer"
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

I was confused with your original question in the GitHub.
https://github.com/networknt/json-schema-validator/issues/322